# Is spark application master per job or per session

Tags: apache-spark

Spark Application Master is per job or per session. In Documentation it states per Application is that equivalent to per job

Comment: https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/apache-spark-resource-management-and-yarn-app-models/
Perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking application master refers only to Spark executed on YARN. Application master is started once per driver (application), with driver being external process (client mode) or running inside master (cluster) mode.

A single Spark driver can submit multiple jobs where is job is a series of transformations followed by an action.

To summarize - it is once per `SparkContext` and can be used to manage multiple jobs.